# Found ID in textbox 1 to find row not applying checkbox choice to that row

Tags: excel, vba

I can't get the following code to find a matching name in column A then to apply the checkbox choice to the pending columns along that row.

Code

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lrEM As Long
    Dim FoundID As Range
    Set FoundID = Sheets("Employee-Software").Range("A:A").Find(What:=TextBox1.Text, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not FoundID Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("Employee-Software").Cells(FoundID.Row, "A").Value = TextBox1.Text
    Else
        lrEM = Sheets("Employee-Software").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Sheets("Employee-Software").Cells(lrEM, "A").Value = TextBox1.Text
    End If
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        Sheets("Employee-Software").Cells(FoundID.Row, "B").Value = "Yes"
        If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
            Sheets("Employee-Software").Cells(FoundID.Row, "B").Value = "No"
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing

Comment: I keep getting a compile error. when I press the submit button it doesn't seem to function correctly.  I'm looking for it to search A for username and then use that row or if it doesn't exist then to use next empty row.

Comment: i have added an answer maybe this is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would not be able to run the code as is because you are missing an `end if`

If you are searching for the textbox value in column A, why would you make it the value of the textbox if found?

You cannot use `FoundID.Row` if the textbox value is not found.

Did you want to use the Yes/No value only if the value is found?

You don't need two checkboxes, if checkbox1=true then "yes" else "no"

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lrEM As Long, x
    Dim FoundID As Range, sh As Worksheet

    Set sh = Sheets("Employee-Software")

    With sh
        x = IIf(CheckBox1 = True, "Yes", "No")
        Set FoundID = .Range("A:A").Find(What:=TextBox1.Text, Lookat:=xlWhole)

        If Not FoundID Is Nothing Then
            'Sheets("Employee-Software").Cells(FoundID.Row, "A").Value = TextBox1.Text

            FoundID.Offset(, 1) = x
        Else

            lrEM = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Cells(lrEM, "A").Value = TextBox1.Text
            .Cells(lrEM, "B").Value = x
        End If

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Not the perfect fix but I can make it work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is required to make it better?

Comment: if the user isn't found it still put the name and checkbox yes or no into the sheet

Comment: Where on the sheet?

Comment: Column B...     I notice if the user name is already in column A it applies checkbox yes or no depending on which one ticked but I noticed if the user name not in the sheet then it doesn't apply the check box answer. It only applies the user name which is in textbox1.

Comment: Wow, that amazing thank you. I was trying to edit it myself but never occurred to me I could write it like that.

Comment: Is it possible for me to add additional columns in the future by adjusting the code with = y or would the code have to be rewritten completely?

Comment: Sure add as much as you want, `.Cells(lrEM, "C").Value = "Her Scarf"`

Answer (score 0):

The only problem i could find was in your last lines in if

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    Sheets("Employee-Software").Cells(FoundID.Row, "B").Value = "Yes"
If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
    Sheets("Employee-Software").Cells(FoundID.Row, "B").Value = "No"
End If
```

It should be

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    Sheets("Employee-Software").Cells(FoundID.Row, "B").Value = "Yes"
else CheckBox2.Value = True Then
    Sheets("Employee-Software").Cells(FoundID.Row, "B").Value = "No"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that I now have an answer that can work for me. Thank you for your time.